# delegate not responding to method call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

Here are my relevant bits of code

This is my changeDaysViewController.h

```
@protocol changedays <NSObject>

    -(void)didChangeDays:(NSNumber *)position :(BOOL )on_off;

@end


#import "AddSiteViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface daysoftheweekViewController : UITableViewController{


}
    @property (retain, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *daysOfTheWeek;
    @property (retain, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *daysOfTheWeekNames;
    @property (assign) id<changedays>deligate;
@end
```

This is the method in my changeDaysViewController.m

```
-(void)updateSwitch:(UIControl*)button withEvent:(UIEvent* )Event{
    UISwitch *swch=(UISwitch *)button;
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)swch.superview;
    if ([swch isOn]) {
         NSLog(@" is onchanged is %d",swch.tag);
        [self.deligate didChangeDays:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.tag] :YES];
    }else{
         NSLog(@" id off row changed is %d",swch.tag);
        [self.deligate didChangeDays:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.tag] :NO];
    }
     [self.deligate didChangeDays:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.tag] :NO];
       NSLog(@" row changed is %d",swch.tag);

}
```

in my add addsiteViewController.h I have implemented the protocol

```
@interface AddSiteViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate ,UIActionSheetDelegate,changedays>{...
```

in the addsiteViewController.m I have

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        daysoftheweekViewController *daysvc=[[daysoftheweekViewController alloc]init];
        daysvc.deligate=self;

    }
    return self;
}
```

and i have

```
-(void)didChangeDays:(NSNumber *)position :(BOOL)on_off{
    [daysOfTheWeek replaceObjectAtIndex:[position integerValue] withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:on_off]];
    NSLog(@"days of the week changed in delegate");
}
```

edit 1
here is the cellorrowatindexpath

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row=[indexPath row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   // if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UISwitch *sw= [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f)];
        cell.accessoryView=sw;
        sw.tag=row;
        [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   // }
    cell.textLabel.text=[daysOfTheWeekNames objectAtIndex:row];
    if([[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:row]integerValue]==1){
        UISwitch *sw=(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView;
        [sw setOn:YES];
    }else{
        UISwitch *sw=(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView;
        [sw setOn:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

when i change the switch on the `UITableView`, I get `"is on changed is 1"` logged on the console from the table view method `-(void) updateSwitch`. However, nothing happens in the `-(void)didChangeDays` method that is in my AddSiteViewController. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So `NSLog(@"days of the week changed in delegate");` doesn't execute? Or does it execute, but first statement doesn't execute?

Comment: there is no output from the console in addsiteViewController, but there is from changedaysViewController

Comment: Are you adding the daysoftheweekViewController as a child view controller somewhere?

Comment: I dont think i am Corey

Comment: Where you are using "daysvc" object? I mean where you are adding it on your view?

Comment: Please share your code for CellforrowAtIndexpath where you are using daysoftheweekViewController

Comment: @user1113101 i am adding that in the init method of my addsiteViewController

Comment: Thats why I asked you this question.wanted to check if you are assigning delegatete on the instance of object  which you are actually using.

Comment: @usaer1113101, like all these things I can see it clearly now, but at the time I was looking for the wrong thing in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own problem.

I was trying to set the delegate in the viewDidLoad method of AddSiteViewControler, where there was no class of changedaysViewController.

i removed

```
daysoftheweekViewController *daysvc=[[daysoftheweekViewController alloc]init];
        daysvc.deligate=self;
```

from my viewdidLoad and added this

```
controller.deligate=self;
```

to

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"daysoftheweek"]){
        daysoftheweekViewController *controller=[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.daysOfTheWeek=daysOfTheWeek;
        controller.daysOfTheWeekNames=daysOfTheWeekNames;
        controller.deligate=self;
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the comments

Comment: i cant do that until tomorrow.. or so it says

Answer (score 0):

Try  `@property (nonatomic, retain) id<changedays>deligate;` in your changeDaysViewController.h & `@synthesize deligate` changeDaysViewController.m